# 2018-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 (KB4343887) Failing

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update, credssp

I've been trying to update the Patches which is failing continuously

[image]

When I click the `Failed to Install`, I popped with the below description

> 2018-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based
>   Systems (KB4343887)
>
> A security issue has been identified in a Microsoft software product
>   that could affect your system. You can help protect your system by
>   installing this update from Microsoft. For a complete listing of the
>   issues that are included in this update, see the associated Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base article. After you install this update, you may have to
>   restart your system.

After some long retry, I can see the below description

> There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again
>   later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact
>   support for information, this may help: (0x800705b4)

I'm trying to update this in order to fix the **CredSSP** (RDP Issue)

[image]

**Update 1**

After Harry Suggestion, I tried to install them manually, but still the updates were not able to install.Pls see below image

[image]

### Update 2:

> Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update
>   with error 0x80070246: Security Update for Windows (KB4343887).
>
> There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again
>   later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact
>   support for information, this may help: (0x800705b4)

When I look into the CBS log i get the below error logs

> 2018-08-24 12:14:40, Error                 CSI
>   00000007@2018/8/24:06:44:40.193 (F)
>   onecore\base\lstring\lblob.cpp(2145): Error STATUS_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER
>   originated in function
>
> 2018-08-24 12:14:40, Error                 CSI    00000008 (F)
>   HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(582) #17525# from
>   Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransactionAnalysis_ICSIInventory::EnumDeploymentReferences(flags
>   = 00000007, tlcid = @0x178e19a9a90, pszSubscription = (null), pszCodebase = (null)) [gle=0x80070246]
>
> 2018-08-24 12:14:40, Error                 CBS    Failed to process
>   single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x80070246 -
>   ERROR_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER]
>
> 2018-08-24 12:14:40, Error                 CSI
>   00000009@2018/8/24:06:44:40.677 (F)
>   onecore\base\lstring\lblob.cpp(2145): Error STATUS_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER
>   originated in function RtlTranscodeLBlobs expression:
>   __rv.UcsCharacter != (0xffffffff) [gle=0x80004005]
>
> 2018-08-24 12:14:40, Error                 CSI    00000008 (F)
>   HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(582) #17525# from
>   Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransactionAnalysis_ICSIInventory::EnumDeploymentReferences(flags
>   = 00000007, tlcid = @0x178e19a9a90, pszSubscription = (null), pszCodebase = (null)) [gle=0x80070246]

Comment: Actually, this image doesn't say anything about the reason.

Comment: @RalfFriedl updated my OP

Comment: Try downloading it from the <[Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4343887)> and installing it manually.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks trying now. Will let you know once done

Comment: @HarryJohnston No luck so far, please see my update 1 in the OP

Comment: You may need to repair Windows.  That's too big a subject to cover properly here, I think, but there's lots of information on the web.  (The simplest - but not necessarily best - approach is an "in-place upgrade". Theoretically, I think you should be able to just run setup.exe from the Windows install media and follow the prompts?)

Comment: @Jayendran - Go to C;\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log file, Ctrl+F, i.e., find error, and share the lines wherever you find the `error` keyword. That'd help you understand the problem.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful please see my update 2 in the OP. Thanks

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Thanks for the response. Please check here in my [onedrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsEgl90kVfyygf1ATVP_5sOW9R4eDw) for the full cbs log

Comment: @Jayendran - It seems your onedrive link is not working! Please check if you can publicly share that log file on Onedrive, or else, you can try other cloud storage providers like Google Drive, Dropbox, etc.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I can able to view the file using my old link. However I've uploaded the same file my [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xjT0C9LYx3kpUtl_NkeFJRzsRSrncbS3/view?usp=sharing). Let me know if you can able to view this

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Is there any update? Could you able to find the root cause of the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem in one of my VM, both via Windows Update and stand-alone update. It pass windows updating and when rebooting it failed at stage of around 74% finished and need to revert back.
Check eventlog and I notice the error message for update comes almost immediately with an error for not be able to stop "Tile Data Model Server" service. So, I disable this service and try again. This time it pass the update.
Just post in case it can help.

Answer (score 1):

Most failures I have seen when installing cumulative updates have been related to disk space.

The cumulative updates are rather large. If the C drive has less than 5GB of free space I would recommend cleaning it up or expanding the drive, then try again.

Comment: There can be **N number of reasons** why *any* update fails! This answer just focuses on one such reason, -1.

Comment: Agreed, I was simply stating the most common cause I've seen for cumulative updates to fail on Server 2016.

Comment: To be honest, I've yet to encounter any server (2016) where the updates are failing because of lack of space! This is the reason why I downvoted this answer.

Comment: Multiple comments related to the issue are here: [Patch Tuesday Megathread (2018-08-14)](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/96zkpa/patch_tuesday_megathread_20180814/e4a91i8/)

Comment: Interestingly, my Windows Server 2016 Datacenter VM in Azure has 7.8 GB free on the C: drive. However, the update fails and the CBS.log includes this: ERROR_DISK_FULL

Comment: After enlarging the C: drive of the server, the update ran just fine.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful: I've seen Windows Server 2016 servers that fail to install updates due to insufficient free disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem after upgrading a 2012 R2 WSUS box to server 2016. I had already downloaded and ran the KB4343887 update from the Microsoft Update Catalog but the install had still failed.
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb4343887

After setting the "Window Internal Database" and "WSUS Server" services to manual and rebooting the box the install ran fine. I confirmed that the services were not running before launching the update.

I was seeing a WindowsUpdateClient EventID 20 in the System log on the server with an error code 0x80070643 when the update was failing.

I am not 100% convinced that my issue actually had to do with the services but you might find this information useful. Your system also likely has a different set of roles installed that might require changing the startup state of other services to manual or disabled in order to emulate the steps I have outlined here that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've updated my question with Update 2. Could you look into it, any idea to resolve this